# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while sending email VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to an email message Application

I used new keyword but still the problem exist.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
  Private myMsg As MailMessage
  Private smtpSender As SmtpClient
  Private Sub CreateMessage()
      myMsg.From = New MailAddress(txtForm.Text.Trim)
      myMsg.To.Add(txtTo.Text.Trim)
      myMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text
      myMsg.Body = txtBody.Text
      myMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
  End Sub
  Private Sub createSmtp()
      smtpSender.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(txtForm.Text.Trim, txtPass.Text.Trim)
      smtpSender.EnableSsl = True
      smtpSender.Host = "smtp.live.com"
      smtpSender.Port = "587"
  End Sub
  Private Sub sendMessage()
      Try
          smtpSender.Send(myMsg)
      Catch ex As Exception
          MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
      End Try
  End Sub
  Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
      CreateMessage()
      createSmtp()
      sendMessage()
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnResetField_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResetField.Click
      txtBody.Clear()
      txtForm.Clear()
      txtPass.Clear()
      txtSubject.Clear()
      txtTo.Clear()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Error in this line: `myMsg.From = New MailAddress(txtForm.Text.Trim)`

Comment: I update the correction from you, but still the error exist
here: smtpSender.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(txtForm.Text.Trim, txtPass.Text.Trim)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

This line isn't complete: `Private myMsg As MailMessage`
It is declared as a variable but never instantiated as a new object.

Should be:

```
 Private myMsg As New MailMessage
 Private smtpSender As New SmtpClient
```

[Objects and classes in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/#to-create-an-object-from-a-class)

Comment: @AbuMus'abAuna The way to thank people on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. You do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.